# ¿Como puedo reedireccionar dependiendo del role?

Tags: php, laravel, users-roles, laravel-permission

quisiera reedireccionar al estar autentificado dependiendo del role,estoy trabajando con laravel permisionss y ya tengo mis dos roles, "Admin" y "Usuarios", quisiera saber como dar referencia a uno de los dos y hacer una validacion en el middleware "redirectifAuthenticated"
,lo tengo tal que asi, como podría verificar el valor de su rol del usuario logeado y redireccionar a la ruta que deseo? :

```php
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

                if(Auth::user()->role = "Admin"){
                    return redirect()->route("dashboard.admin");//Ruta designada
                }
                if(Auth::user()->role = "Usuarios"){
                    return redirect()->route("dashboard.users");//Ruta designada
                }
                // return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Cabe recalcar que no tengo un campo role,solo lo estoy indicando como ejemplo,para llamar a la relacion que se produce al migrar las tablas de laravel permissions y su conexion con el modelo User

Algo tal que asi,si hay una mejor forma de producirlo estoy abierto a las recomendaciones,de antemano,muchas gracias!

Editado

```php
  public function adminlte_desc(){
        $role = null;
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole(["Admin"])){
            $role = "Administrador";
        }else{
            $role = "Usuario";
        }
        return $role;
    }
```

Editado x2 :

Me indica este error :
**Undefined method 'hasRole'.intelephense(1013)**

y Aqui hay imagenes de referencia :

Primero la cabecera y luego el metodo como tal:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente necesitas usar el método `hasRole` que te proporciona el paquete de Spatie al modelo de usuario, le pasas un arreglo con los roles que quieres validar si existe alguno asignado al usuario, puedes utilizarlo así:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards) {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

                if(Auth::user()->hasRole(["Admin"])){
                    return redirect()->route("dashboard.admin");//Ruta designada
                }
                if(Auth::user()->hasRole(["Usuarios"])){
                    return redirect()->route("dashboard.users");//Ruta designada
                }
                // return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Edición:**

Este es un helper que hice para obtener los roles y mostrarlos en pantalla

```
function roleUser($user, $badge=true) {
    $num=1;
    $roles="";
    foreach ($user['roles'] as $rol) {
        if ($user->hasRole($rol->name)) {
            $roles.=($user['roles']->count()==$num) ? $rol->name : $rol->name."<br>";
            $num++;
        }
    }

    if (!is_null($user['roles']) && !empty($roles)) {
        if ($badge) {
            return '<span class="badge badge-primary">'.$roles.'</span>';
        } else {
            return $roles;
        }
    } else {
        if ($badge) {
            return '<span class="badge badge-dark">Desconocido</span>';
        } else {
            return 'Desconocido';
        }
    }
}

{!! roleUser(Auth::user(), false) !!}
```

Comment: Hola!Te queria preguntar, y en caso de que quisiera comprobar el role en un modelo?,estoy usando adminlte3 y quisiera imprimir el role que pertenece determinado usuario,por ejemplo algo tal que asi,lo pongo como  edicion!,Pero el problema me indica es que el metodo "hasRole" No existe,ya que ,probablemente esta en el modelo

Comment: Tengo un helper que suelo utilizar para eso, básicamente recorre la colección de roles para guardarlos en una variable y lo muestro en pantalla, te lo dejo en edición

Comment: Y en tu helper no te indica un error sobre metodo no encontrado "hasRole"? , y en caso de que no, como podría solucionar aquello,porque a mi me indica eso :(

Comment: Es extraño que te pase eso si estas colocando la colección de un User, tendría que ver el error porque no es algo mal en el código que colocaste

Comment: Agregue una nueva edicion para indicar mas contexto!, Gracias bryant por tomarte el tiempo!